# i get thread sleep error in C++11 threading

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I created a thread using C++11 `thread` class and I want the thread to sleep in a loop.
When the `this_thread::sleep_for()` function is called, I get exception saying:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable '_Now' was
>   corrupted.

My code is below:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds duration( 5000 );
while (m_connected)
{
    this->CheckConnection();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that error is in `sleep_for`, not in `CheckConnection`? What compiler you use?

Comment: is _Now variable in the implementation of sleep_for()?

Comment: i compile using VS2012. @ForEveR

Comment: i see that it fails in sleep_for when  i debug it. @ForEveR

Comment: Do you get the error without the line this->CheckConnection() as well ?

Comment: @xyzt What version of 2012 VS? RC, or newer?

Comment: Where is _Now defined? What does your CheckConnection() function do? What happens if you comment out this->CheckConnection();?

Answer (score 0):

I presume `_Now` is a local variable somewhere deep in implementation of `sleep_for`. If it gets corrupt, either there is bug in that function (unlikely) or some other part of your application is writing to dangling pointers (much more likely).

The most likely cause is that you, some time before calling the `sleep_for`, give out pointer to local variable that stays around and is written to by other thread while this thread sleeps.

If you were on Linux, I'd recommend you to try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (though I am not certain it can catch invalid access to stack), but on Windows I don't know about any tool for debugging this kind of problems. You can do careful review and you can try disabling various parts of functionality to see when the problem goes away to narrow down where it might be.

I also used to use [duma](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) library with some success, but it can only catch invalid access to heap, not stack.

Note: Both clang and gcc are further in implementing C++11 than MSVC++, so if you don't use much Windows-specific stuff, it might be easy to port and try valgrind on it. Gcc and especially clang are also known for giving much better static diagnostics than MSVC++, so if you compile it with gcc or clagn, you may get some warning that will point you to the problem.

Comment: 'std::this_thread::sleep_for' is a standard library function. so how can it a local varialble,_Now, can be corrupted? i do not access it.. @Jan Hudec

Comment: @xyzt: Local variable is allocated on the stack. Either some other variable in earlier called local function was allocated to the same address and you kept pointer to it somewhere and now are writing it, or there is a local array elsewhere on the stack and you write invalid offset (would have to be negative/high enough to wrap as stack grows down on common platforms) that happens to be where this local variable lives.